# Python: what does Thread.is_alive *exactly* mean?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.9

In Python 3.9.10, I am stumbling on the following very unsettling behaviour:

```
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        liveness = self.is_alive()
        logging.debug(f"Am I alive? {liveness}")  # prints FALSE!!!
        ...  # do some work involving asyncio and networking
        ...  # (specifically, I'm using aiohttp) and I know this work is
        ...  # actually being done because I can see its side-effects
        ...  # from across the network.
        liveness = self.is_alive()
        logging.debug(f"Am I alive? {liveness}")  # prints False AGAIN!!!
        ...  # go on with that work (still detectable and detected)
        liveness = self.is_alive()
        logging.debug(f"Am I alive? {liveness}")  # still False...
```

Under some conditions, that call to `is_alive()` is returning *False*. Now, I'm not doing anything weird like redefining methods in `MyThread` that I'm not supposed to, or messing around with internals of anything.

My question is, under normal circumstances, is there any situation in which `Thread.is_alive` would return `False` after the thread has started, but while it is still doing work? (By the way, doing mostly Python work, not some C code running in the background.)

## More Details

There is a main thread, and two worker threads. It goes on something like this. The following code runs in the main thread:

```
exit_signal = threading.Event()
workers = {}
# pass them the exit_signal so they know when to stop:
workers['connect_to_server_1'] = MyThread("server1.com", exit_signal)
workers['connect_to_server_1'].start()
workers['connect_to_server_2'] = MyThread("server2.com", exit_signal)
workers['connect_to_server_2'].start()

# wait until the process gets a SIGINT (user hits ^C)
try:
    for w in workers.values():
        w.join()  # will never return
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    logging.info("ok, user wants to quit, let's quit")
else:
    logging.critical("threads have quit on their own")  # never happens

# list thread statuses
w = workers['connect_to_server_1']
logging.debug(f"Is {w} alive? {w.is_alive()}")  # prints FALSE
w = workers['connect_to_server_2']
logging.debug(f"Is {w} alive? {w.is_alive()}")  # prints TRUE

# For debugging purposes, give the workers some more time to keep doing
# their jobs. This here is an interesting time window: the main thread
# has already received ^C, but the workers are supposedly not aware of
# that.
time.sleep(10)
# Finally, tell workers to stop, and wait for them to go:
exit_signal.set()
workers['connect_to_server_1'].join()
workers['connect_to_server_2'].join()
logging.info("all good, bye!")
```

What happens is this

- Before I hit `^C`, I see in my log output messages from both workers telling me that they are heatlhy and successfully doing their jobs; more importantly, those "Am I alive?" messages (from the first code snippet at the top) always say `True`.
- After I hit `^C`, I see the log messages from the main thread checking the `is_alive()` status of both workers. I expected it to tell me that both workers are alive, since the interrupt signal always interrupts just the main thread. However, it tells me that the second worker is alive, but the first is not.
- After that, while the main thread is blocked on that `time.sleep(10)` call, I still see messages from both workers in the log output. Both workers tell me that they are successfully doing their jobs (which can be verified by log messages from the other server they're talking to). However, everytime the first worker logs the "Am I alive?" message, it says `False`. WTF?
- Finally, I set the `exit_signal`.

  - I see a message from the second worker (the one that was saying `"Am I alive? True"`), telling me that it received the signal, and then it goes on doing its shutdown routine, closing files and sockets etc.
  - I don't see any message from the other worker, and I can't see anywhere anything that indicates that he has received that signal, *except for the fact that the `join` method on its thread returned successfully*!

## Closing thoughts

This code has been running in Python 3.6 for months, usually with around 15 workers instead of 2, and this issue never happened. It only happens when I try to run it in Python 3.9. It's somewhat easily reproducible: when I run that service with Python 3.9, around half of the time everything works perfectly, but the in the other half I get scared by this zombie thread telling me that it's dead, yet it's talking to me.

Also, the zombie thread is always the one talking to *one specific server*, which makes me think that this might be a problem with that one server's SSL certificate, or its implementation of the websocket protocol, but whatever, I don't control that one server. What I do control is the this instance of `threading.Thread` which should be *either dead or walking upright, but not both*.

What am I missing here?

Comment: "Something like this" isn't enough. We need to see a [mcve].

Comment: My wild guess would be that either you're misreading your logs, or somewhere in your code, you're doing `thread.run()` instead of `thread.start()`.

Comment: I spent this afternoon trying to reduce the code to something that both reproduced the example AND could be made public, but I couldn't, sorry :( My real question, though, is asked before the "Details" header, and is purely theoretical: under which circumstances would `Thread.is_alive` return False after the thread has started, but while it is still doing work?

Comment: Only in cases you don't think you're in, like if you screwed with the internals somehow or overrode something you shouldn't.

Comment: well, that's the answer I didn't want, because it doesn't help me hehehe but thanks!

Comment: ...wait. Actually, looking at the source code, there might be a bug where interrupting a `join` call spuriously marks a thread stopped. I see a check that doesn't look right in the `join` method.

Comment: Yeah, this looks like an actual `join` bug. The [fix](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/1ecb641b887af2feb026a266e2fceedee0815ca8) for [Python bug 45274](https://bugs.python.org/issue45274) uses the wrong check to see whether it managed to acquire a lock - it just checks whether *anyone* has that lock.

Comment: Yes! I realized that "the one thread that always gets weird" is just the first of the list, which is the one currently being joined. I was trying exactly that for a reproducible example.

Comment: Try [this](https://pastebin.com/d9fDusQn) and hit Ctrl-C after it says "joining now".

Comment: Same with Python 3.10.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is a recently-introduced bug in the threading implementation. `Thread.join` calls the internal method `Thread._wait_for_tstate_lock`, and that method was recently [changed](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/1ecb641b887af2feb026a266e2fceedee0815ca8) to look like [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.10/Lib/threading.py#L1059):

```
try:
    if lock.acquire(block, timeout):
        lock.release()
        self._stop()
except:
    if lock.locked():
        # bpo-45274: lock.acquire() acquired the lock, but the function
        # was interrupted with an exception before reaching the
        # lock.release(). It can happen if a signal handler raises an
        # exception, like CTRL+C which raises KeyboardInterrupt.
        lock.release()
        self._stop()
    raise
```

The `if lock.locked()` check was an attempt to fix a hanging issue that occurred if this method was interrupted by Ctrl-C between the `lock.acquire` and the `lock.release` immediately afterward, but the check is wrong. It doesn't check if the previous `lock.acquire` call acquired the lock. It just checks if the lock is locked at all! The lock is almost *always* locked, and particularly, it's supposed to be locked the entire time a thread is alive.

This means that if you interrupt the `lock.acquire` call in this method with Ctrl-C, the code releases the lock (that someone else is holding) and calls `self._stop` to perform end-of-thread cleanup, including marking the thread as not alive any more. That's why your `is_alive` calls are returning `False`.

Comment: for anyone else reaching this link, this issue has been reported as [bpo-46726](https://bugs.python.org/issue46726) by (or so I suppose) @user2357112supportsMonica